# Slide from left to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, slide

I have been searching and tried alot of things but I can't get the solution;

```
#bar {
    width: 2em;
    height: 15em;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -1.7em;
    background: rgba(22, 43, 58, 0.4);
}
#button {
    width: 2em;
    height: 1.3em;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0.7em;
    margin-left: 0.em;
    background: rgba(22, 43, 58, 0.4);
    color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.7);
    font-size: 1em;
    border-radius:0px 5px 5px 0px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

I would like when I press the button the bar slides to the right.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button').click(function () {
        $("#bar").show('slide', {
            direction: 'right'
        }, 1500);
    });
});
```

this is the HTML for the part

```
<div class="apps border">
    <div id="bar"></div>
    <div id="button">>></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/gc3b8n9q/)

Comment: Could you include the HTML you are using?

Comment: i have added the HTML, sorry ! i tried all kinds of the things with the positioning etc.

Comment: Demo updated to include jQueryUI.

Comment: Could this be caused by your CSS? E.g. `float: left;`? I removed that and `margin-left` for `#bar`, and it seems to be working.

Comment: no this is not caused by float: left or margin-left i tried this too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the updated version: https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/gc3b8n9q/

In JS, direction should be 'left'

```
$("#bar").show('slide', {
  direction: 'left'
}, 1500);
```

Also in CSS (not directly needed)

```
#bar {
    width: 20em; //can try make bigger
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply ! but strangely it's not working in my code, i can see it work in JSfiddle though !

Comment: Check if there are some other CSS rules related to #bar or #button or some other JS bindings on #bar or #button elements. And typos of course

Comment: i rebuild the whole page, and it works now, don't really know what the problem was though.. :/